# jQuery dúvida todos os elementos são afetados pela função

Tags: jquery

Tenho a seguinte função, que funciona para fazer a troca da flecha de um acordeon quando estiver ativo (aberto), de flecha para baixo para inverter para cima, e depois voltar ao estado original, mas todas as flechas são afetadas, e não somente a que estou clicando no momento, como posso resolver isso? tentei utilizar this mas não funcionou para essa situação:

```
 function controlAccordeon() {
    var accordeonTitle = $('.accordeon-open-title');
    var angleDown = $('.fa-angle-down');
    var angleUp = $('.fa-angle-up');

    accordeonTitle.click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        angleUp.toggleClass('hide');
        angleDown.toggleClass('hide');
    });
}
```

Comment: `angleUp.toggleClass('hide');` e `angleDown.toggleClass('hide');` tem de ser feitos por navegação no html e não dessa forma senão acerta em todos. Se mostrar o html correspondente ajuda a obter a resposta correta

Comment: Coloque um id no elemento que vc quer mexer e chama por id ao invés de classe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

se angleDown e angleUp sao filhas da accordeonTitle é só chamar de dentro da função click **$('.fa-angle-up',this).toggleClass('hide');** mas sem ver o html não tem como ajudar muito.

Comment: era exatamente isso, deu certo, obrigada !

Answer (score 1):

A regra costuma ser: recolhe todos menos o que foi clicado, esse recebe toggle.

Sugiro ainda controlares as setas com CSS, assim só precisas mudar a classe `active` e o resto "acontece por sí".

Exemplo:

```js
function controlAccordeon() {
  var accordeonTitle = $('.accordeon-open-title');

  accordeonTitle.click(function() {
    accordeonTitle.not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
}

controlAccordeon();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.accordeon-open-title {
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: height .8s;
}

.accordeon-open-title.active {
  height: 200px;
}

/* setas */

.accordeon-open-title .fa-angle-down {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.8s;
}

.accordeon-open-title.active .fa-angle-down {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="accordeon-open-title">
  <h1>Titulo 1 <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></h1>
  <p>Conteúdo</p>
</div>
<div class="accordeon-open-title">
  <h1>Titulo 2 <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></h1>
  <p>Conteúdo</p>
</div>
```